# Minimal polynomial always equals minimal annihilating polynomial of some vector

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map. let $m_T$ be its minimal polynomial and $m_{T,x}$ be the minimal (degree monic) polynomial such that $m_{T,x}(T).x=0$ for $x\in V$.

**Question.** Is it possible to show $m_T=m_{T,x}$ for some $x\in V$ without using rational forms / primary decomposition?

**Edit.** For a simpler case, can we show (without using rational forms / primary decomposition) that if $\deg m_T=\dim V=d$ (i.e. $m_T$ is also the characteristic polynomial of $T$) then $x,Tx,\dots,T^{d-1}x$ is a basis of $V$ for some $x$ ?